# Java8 How to convert 3-level nested list into nested HashMap using stream and lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I'm trying to convert a 3 level nested list into Nested HashMap.

The function declaration for the same is:

`Map<Key1, Map<Key2, List<String>>> transformToMap (List<Obj1> inputList)`

The `inputList` internally has nested list which again has nested list.

The code I've wrote is using traditional for loop as follow:

```
private Map<Key1 , Map<Key2, List<String>>> reverseLookup(List<Key2> key2List){
    Map<Key1 , Map<Key2, List<String>>>  resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    key2List.forEach(key2->{
        List<ElementObject> elementObjects = key2.getElementObjects();
        elementObjects.forEach(elementObject->{
            final String name = elementObject.getName();
            elementObject.getApplicablePeriods().forEach(applicablePeriod-> {
                Key1 key1 = applicablePeriod.getKey1();
                Map<Key2, List<String>> map2 = resultMap.get(key1);
                if(map2 == null){
                    map2 = new HashMap<>();
                }
                List<String> stringList = map2.get(key2);
                if(stringList == null){
                    stringList = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                stringList.add(name);
                map2.put(key2, stringList);
                resultMap.put(key1, map2);
            });
        });
    });

    return resultMap;
}
```

The class structure for the same is as follow:

```
class Key2{

    List<ElementObject> elementObjects;

    //getters & setters
}

class ElementObject {
    String name;
    //few more params
    List<ApplicablePeriod> applicablePeriods;
     //getters & setters
}

class ApplicablePeriod{
    Key1 key1;
    //getters & setters
}

class Key1{
    //some parameters
    //getters & setters
}
```

The above code is fulfilling my expectations.

What will be the efficient way to transform it into stream lambda using `Collectors.toMap` ?

I've tried something as follow:

```
inputList
        .stream()
        .flatMap(item -> item.getObj2List().stream())
        .flatMap(nestedItem -> nestedItem.getKeyList().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a-> a.get()))
```

But not getting what should be the next step in `Collectors.toMap`.
Not able to handle `final String name = nestedItem.getName();` which is used just before 3rd for loop.

Let me know the way to solve this.

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Comment: I'm trying something like: `inputList.stream().flatMap(item -> item.getObj2List().stream()).flatMap(nestedItem -> nestedItem.getKeyList().stream()).collect(Collectors.toMap(a-> a.get()))` But not getting what should be the next step in `Collectors.toMap`. Not able to handle `final String name = nestedItem.getName();` which is used just before 3rd for loop.

Comment: Edit the question and update it with the attempt for people to help you out further.

Comment: Is that compiling? It seems that when you do `nestedMap.put(item,stringList);`, your item is of type `Obj1` when it should be `Key2`

Comment: @Bentaye I've updated it. Actual code is bit more complex, I just simplified it so that everyone can understand. Missed this change while writing above code. my bad.

Comment: and `Key2` has a method `getObj2List`, correct? Could you provide the interfaces for each of these classes?

Comment: @Bentaye I've modified code to look much simpler & also added classes for reference

Comment: @Bentaye did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: You can look into Collectors.groupingBy(). 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector

However, as a suggestion, I would instead use the stream API to filter for the item in my object hierarchy instead of transforming into a map unless there is a specific reason you need a map. You're processing through your data model to create a slightly different data model instead of simply grabbing what you need and returning.

Also, IMO, don't force the use of .forEach. Nested Lambdas become tricky to read. Nothing wrong with using a for() loop with logic broken down into smaller methods.

Comment: Key2 is in essence a compound object containing a list. Do you really want to use this as a key for the resulting map? How is ```equals()``` defined then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any test data to see if it creates something similar as your traditional code. But take a look at this and let me know if it helps:

```java
key2List.stream().flatMap((key2) -> key2.elementObjects.stream().map((element) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(key2, element)))
    .flatMap((entry) -> entry.getValue().applicablePeriods.stream().map((period) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(period.key1, new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().name))))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())))));
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the problem is that you want to access multiple levels of abstractions inside of the same `Stream`, this is usually not possible unless you have

- Nested streams
- An object that can hold references to higher objects

I fixed it in the second way.

I'm using [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16) and the following features

- `Collectors#mapMulti`
- `Collectors#groupingBy`
- A locally defined `record`

```java
private Map<Key1, Map<Key2, List<String>>> reverseLookup(List<Key2> key2List) {
    record HolderObject(Key2 key2, ElementObject elementObject, ApplicablePeriod applicablePeriod){}

    return key2List.stream()
            .mapMulti((Key2 key2, Consumer<HolderObject> consumer) -> {
                List<ElementObject> elementObjects = key2.getElementObjects();
                elementObjects.forEach(elementObject ->
                        elementObject.getApplicablePeriods().forEach(applicablePeriod -> {
                            consumer.accept(new HolderObject(
                                    key2,
                                    elementObject,
                                    applicablePeriod
                            ));
                        })
                );
            })
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    h -> h.applicablePeriod().getKey1(),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            HolderObject::key2,
                            Collectors.mapping(
                                    h -> h.elementObject().getName(),
                                    Collectors.toList()
                            )
                    )
            ));
}
```

And here is a [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) compatible solution

```java
private Map<Key1, Map<Key2, List<String>>> reverseLookup(List<Key2> key2List) {
    return key2List
            .stream()
            .flatMap(key2 -> key2.getElementObjects()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(elementObject -> elementObject.getApplicablePeriods()
                            .stream()
                            .map(applicablePeriod -> new HolderObject(
                                    key2,
                                    elementObject,
                                    applicablePeriod
                            ))))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    h -> h.getApplicablePeriod().getKey1(),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            HolderObject::getKey2,
                            Collectors.mapping(
                                    h -> h.getElementObject().getName(),
                                    Collectors.toList()
                            )
                    )
            ));
}

@Value
public static class HolderObject {
    Key2 key2;
    ElementObject elementObject;
    ApplicablePeriod applicablePeriod;
}
```